# call a function in servlet through jsp url

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to sort a field for which i call a servlet(index.java) using a hyperlink from my jsp file (index.jsp).. 
When the user clicks the heading (which is "ID") the sort() function should be called from the servlet and should get sorted. 
additional info: i collect the elements from the database in index.java and print it on the index.jsp page using the requestdispatcher object.

Comment: why not use a f/w like struts/ spring? you'll have keep a mapping in your servlet and lookup based on different urls (mapped to same servlet in web.xml) or pass method name as request param. either case, invoke using reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me you can not call a method of the servlet directly from the JSP.
One thing you can do is you can call a servlet which in its service() method do the sorting for you and returns the same structure data (but now in sorted mode) to the JSP.

You can call this using AJAX (which refreshes the part of that page only) or by refreshing the the whole page.

Comment: thank you naveed. I din't use AJAX. Instead I created an extra hidden text field for "asc" and "desc" and send it to the same servlet and pass that asc and desc to the query and get the updated results displayed in my index.jsp page.